# the profiler in android studio 3.3.2 stuck in loading

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried many times to start profiler in android studio but it still loading and never start 
[profiler stuck in loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bI4j.jpg)

note: I enabled ADB.